# Is there a way to style Angular Material Tabs like this?

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material, material-ui, material-design

I am trying to style my mat-tabs like this
[image: Tabs Image one]

[image]

But I am having some issues with loosing the white border under the currently selected tab. Adding a bottom border to mat-tab-label-active (with ::ng-deep) still leaves some of the mat-tab-labels' red border visible, even if I apply z-index to the active tab. Is this possible?
See current code below

```css
::ng-deep {
    .mat-tab-label-active {
        background: $white;
        border-top: 0.25em solid $carmine;
        border-right: 0.25em solid $carmine;
        border-left: 0.25em solid $carmine;
        border-bottom: 0.1em solid $white;
        z-index: 100;
    }
    .mat-tab-labels {
        border-bottom: 0.25em solid $carmine;

    }
    .mat-tab-group.mat-primary .mat-ink-bar, {
        background-color: $white;
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qmkyep?file=src/app/tab-group-basic-example.scss)
The first tab still shows the container background colour. I'm also struggling to stop the animation on the transition between tabs as the selected tab turns white before its encapsulated by the red border

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
::ng-deep {
  .mat-tab-label-active {
    background: white;
  }

  .mat-tab-labels {
    border-bottom: 2px solid crimson;
  }

  .mat-tab-group.mat-primary .mat-ink-bar {
    background-color: transparent;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-top: 2px solid crimson;
    border-left: 2px solid crimson;
    border-right: 2px solid crimson;
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
    height: 50px;
  }

  .mat-tab-nav-bar, .mat-tab-header {
    border-bottom: none;
  }
}
```

https://angular-qmkyep.stackblitz.io/

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qmkyep?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftab-group-basic-example.scss)

Comment: This is great and the most useful method I've tried. However, due to the transparency on the tabs, the first tab has the lilac come through on the tab background on page init. This only goes away when you start selecting tabs. I've tried changing the background to white and target the text on the tab to up the z-index but had no luck so far

Comment: Please share a Stackblitz to see what's wrong.

Comment: Here is StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qmkyep?file=src/app/tab-group-basic-example.scss

Comment: Please check the stackblitz link, its the same one I posted